# Cucumber JVM: Run Tagged hooks before global hook

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber JVM for selenium Tests. I have a few Test cases to register the user and after each test I want to delete the user.

And so I have created a new tagged hook which I am using for these tests. as mentioned below

**The problem is Gloabl hook `tearDown` runs before tagged hook `deleteUser` which closed the browser and so I can't run steps to delete the user.**

is there any way I can run `deleteUser` before `tearDown` as part of hooks.

```
@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario){
    System.out.println("teardown");  
    closeDriver();
}

@After("@deleteNewUser")
public void deleteUser(){
    System.out.println("deleteUser");
 }
```

This is how I am using these hooks

```
@deleteNewUser
Scenario: Register user
  Given New User is registered
```

**Output**

> teardown
>
> deleteUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **order attribute** on the `After` hook. The highest value of order will be executed first. Reverse for `Before` hook.

```
@After(order=5)
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario){
    System.out.println("teardown");  
    closeDriver();
}

@After("@deleteNewUser", order=10)
public void deleteUser(){
    System.out.println("deleteUser");
 }
```